# Print raw data to label printer (QRCode) - ESC/P with PHP

Tags: php, printing, qr-code, escpos

I'm trying to print QRCode-labels on a Brother QL580 label printer directly with PHP (Version 5.6).
The function i'm calling to print a QRCode returns:

```
return chr(27) . 'iQ32000020' . $this->dataString . chr(92) . chr(92) . chr(92);
```

This works only in part. The QRCode is printed correctly (the `$dataString` is included) but the preceding 8 parameters seem to be ignored.
I want to increase the cell size of the QRCode (first parameter) but changing the value does not take effect.
The documentation says:

[ESC/P QRCode documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxNtp.png)

Any help would be apreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the solution by myself ;)
One has to use hex for the parameters to work.
Like this:
`return chr(27) . "iQ\x03\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00" . $this->dataString . chr(92) . chr(92) . chr(92);`